# What is the difference between the actual distance covered by a projected object and the displacement?

Tags: definition, distance, displacement

What is the difference between the actual [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) covered by a projected object and the [displacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_%28vector%29)?

> *A stone was projected with an angle of projection of 30 and it covered a horizontal distance of 6 meter find the velocity of the projection.*

Comment: What does your textbook say about the two?

Answer (score 1):

In general, displacement is the distance from initial position to final position, where as distance is the length along the path that was taken.

For example, if I run around a 400 m oval and return to my starting position, the distance I have traveled is 400 m, but the displacement is 0 since my initial and final positions are equal (therefore my average velocity is 0, but my average speed is not).

In the question you have asked however, they specify "horizontal distance", which is effectively the same as "horizontal displacement" in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Displacement is the **straight line distance** from points A to B.

Distance is the **travel** length from points A to B ie A -> C -> D -> B