# Beginner wondering about displacement

Tags: definition, distance, displacement

At the moment I am going to a physics camp. I also do vex robotics. I am trying to use the equations to help me build my robot perfectly. Right now I'm working on how fast the throwing wheels should spin, So I'm working on a my first projectile problem, but I want to know, what is [displacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_%28vector%29)? I know it's going from one place to another, but is it the shortest direction or the long way. Responses are appreciated.

Comment: I think your question needs fleshing out a bit more - you assume to much and/or are confusing your question with needless specifics. What is vex robtics? What are "the equations". If you just want to know what is meant by the physics term "displacement" try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(vector)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143043/2451

Comment: okay, I tried looking there, but just to be sure, if a ball goes up 1 meter, and goes down only 0.5 meters before you catch it, is the displacement 0.5 meters or 1.5 meters? In addition i was specific because whenever I'm on this site for programming they always say to be more specific and I presumed that it was that way of thinking across the site. Thanks! (pre-emptivly)

Comment: thanks Qmechanic. That link helped much more that tutor.com. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Displacement is a vector quantity that starts from an object's initial starting point to the objects end point. Yes, it is the shortest distance between the initial and final point, despite if the object takes many detours and turns to get from the initial to the final point.